# Lest number of terms for a partial sum to estimate sum within error

Tags: summation, estimation

[image]

So here is my question. I used the Alternating series to prove that the sum does converge absolutely, so it converges in general.

I then tried to say that $\frac{1}{n^4}<10^{-8}$ and solve for n to find the minimum number of terms. Is that correct or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. A standard estimate of the remainder. One may recall that for a *standard* alternating series the absolute value of the [remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Approximating_sums) is less or equal to the absolute value of its first term, giving here
$$
\left|R_k:=\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^4}\right|\le \frac1{(k+1)^4}.
$$ One may then solve
$$
\frac1{(k+1)^4}\le 10^{-8} \implies k=99.
$$
**Remark**. One may prove that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^4}=\left(1-\frac18\right)\zeta(4)=\frac{7\pi^4}{720},
$$ and that
$$
\left|\frac{7\pi^4}{720}-R_{83}\right|>10^{-8},\quad \left|\frac{7\pi^4}{720}-R_{84}\right|\le10^{-8}.
$$ The least value is $k=\color{red}{84}.$

Comment: Oh no! I completely missied the $b_{n+1}$ >.< .

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/EstimatingSeries.aspx

Thanks! I have to be careful next time :( .

Comment: Remark. This is does not prove that $k=99$ is the least value.

Comment: I know. I looked at a formal proof for a very similar question but it does not make so much sense.

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty You are welcome.

Comment: @oliver Oloa, I know what the exact sum of this series is but is there any way to formally prove that 99 is the mimimum number of terms necessary for that?

Would I just simply take the exact value and subtract the 99th partial sum?

Comment: Please, see my edit, the least value of $k$ is $84$.

Comment: That's it. I was wondering how that worked. Thanks a lot!